# Outer join on 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables, Client, Tool and ClientTools.
One client can have multiple tools, so ClientTools acts as pivot table (only containing Id's).

What I would like to do is, for a given Client, to have a full list of tools, and a flag indicating whether the Client has this tool or not.

Where I came so far is :

```
select      t.Id as [ToolId],
            t.Name as [ToolName],
            Cast(case when c.Id is NULL then 0 else 1 end as bit) as [HasThisTool],
from        Tool t
Left join   ClientTools ct
on          t.Id = ct.ToolId
Left Join   Client c
on          ct.ClientId = c.Id
```

Which correctly gives me all Tools, but for all Clients (duplicating Tool rows when multiple clients own this Tool).

But as soon as I use a where close to filter to the selected client, my query only returns the rows for this client (so the left join is not made anymore).

I tried adding `where c.Id = 123`
and 
`where (c.Id = 123 or c.Id is null)` but none worked.

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post your WHERE clause?

Comment: Done. (Oh, welcome minimum characters count limitation !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select      t.Id as [ToolId],
            t.Name as [ToolName],
            Cast(case when ct.Id is NULL then 0 else 1 end as bit) as [HasThisTool]
from        Tool t
Left join   ClientTools ct
on          t.Id = ct.ToolId and ct.ClientId = @ClientId
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark !  I didn't know I had to use a `and` in the join clause.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, if you are not retrieving the name of your client, you don't need to join to that table (but its not the real problem). Try this:

```
select      t.Id as [ToolId],
            t.Name as [ToolName],
            Cast(case when ct.Id is NULL then 0 else 1 end as bit) as [HasThisTool]
from        Tool t
Left join   (SELECT * FROM ClientTools WHERE ClientId = @ClientId) ct
on          t.Id = ct.ToolId
```

Comment: This is a simplified sample from a real case.  I tried adding this where clause, but the result is only getting the rows where the ClientId is the one specified, the other don't appear as NULL (as expected)

Comment: @Shimrod - Modified my answer, try now

Comment: Thanks Lamak, it seems to do the trick, however I prefer Mark's solution, I find it being sexier than yours (no offence).  Here's an upvote for you !

Answer (score 0):

If you switch up the order of your tables, it should work:

```
select      t.Id as [ToolId],
            t.Name as [ToolName],
            Cast(case when t.Id is NULL then 0 else 1 end as bit) as [HasThisTool],
from        Client c
Left join   ClientTools ct
on          c.Id = ct.ClientId
Left Join   Tool t
on          ct.ToolId = t.Id
where       c.id = 123
```

In essence, you're saying that Client (not tool) is what determines whether a row shows up in the result set or not.

Comment: I want to opposite, display each Tool (each time), and if the Client has this tool, display him on the row.  But thanks for your answer.